# how to set CacheCow Expires for an action?

Tags: asp.net, caching, asp.net-web-api, cachecow

I create asp.net webapi and try to use **CacheCow** but i can't set the Expiration time like **CacheOutput**

```
[CacheOutput(ClientTimeSpan = 100, ServerTimeSpan = 100)]
public IEnumerable<string> Get()
{
    return new string[] { "value1", "value2" };
}
```

How can I do this with **CacheCow** ?

Answer (score 0):

Cachecow specify caching policy. you can specify above by using below

```
[HttpCacheControlPolicy(true, 100)]
public IEnumerable<string> Get()
{
    return new string[] { "value1", "value2" };
 }
```